# HTML file download using MVC FileResult looks different when downloading from server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have written some Asp.Net MVC code that returns an Html file FileResult.

```
 var stream = new MemoryStream();
 var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
 writer.Write(htmlReport);
 writer.Flush();
 stream.Position = 0;

 return File(stream, "text/html", fileName);
```

Using my local environment the HTML file looks fine when opened but after deploying to the server and downloading the same file some unwanted Â characters can be seen. How could the difference in server environments be affecting a file which is downloaded to the users pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the file encoding. You are most likely using UTF8, but other formats are available.

```
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Why use the `StreamWriter` at all?

```
return Content(htmlReport, "text/html", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Or if you want to be using `File` as your return result try:

```
byte[] bArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(htmlReport);
return File(bArray, "text/html", fileName);
```

Comment: I was just thinking that but it does say that UTF8 is the default. I'll try it.

Comment: @Jim Added a couple of other options.